# BeautifulSoup cannot parse the html tags which don't have closing element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is the HTML code I working on it

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>sdasdsadsad</title>
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="local:80" />
<meta name="description" content="sdddsdsdsdsdsd">
<meta name="keywords" content="3333333333333333">
<meta property="og:title" content="444444444444444444444444">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:description" content="dsdsdsdsddsds">

</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I want to get the line contains tag "`<meta name = description`" , which doesn't have close element `</meta>`. There is my code

```
import glob, os, re, urllib2, codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer


html_doc = """
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>sdasdsadsad</title>
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="local:80" />
<meta name="description" content="sdddsdsdsdsdsd">
<meta name="keywords" content="3333333333333333">
<meta property="og:title" content="444444444444444444444444">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:description" content="dsdsdsdsddsds">

</head>
<body></body>
</html>
"""



soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
aa = soup.find("meta", {"name":"description"})
print aa.encode("utf-8")
```

Running the Python code, but the console show

```
<meta content="sdddsdsdsdsdsd" name="description">
<meta content="3333333333333333" name="keywords">
<meta content="444444444444444444444444" property="og:title">
<meta content="article" property="og:type">
<meta content="dsdsdsdsddsds" property="og:description">
</meta></meta></meta></meta></meta>
```

But if "`<meta content="sdddsdsdsdsdsd" name="description">`" has close element `</meta>`, I can get exactly the line:

```
<meta content="sdddsdsdsdsdsd" name="description"> </meta>
```

Would you like to tell me why the reason BeautifulSoup get all HTML tag under `<meta name = description` , and how to get the line contains `<meta name = description`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [lxml](http://lxml.de/installation.html) module as the [parser](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) and it will work, I've tested it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
aa = soup.find("meta", {"name":"description"})

print aa.encode('utf-8')

# console output
<meta content="sdddsdsdsdsdsd" name="description"/>
```

Comment: Thank Pizza! It works. Just would like to ask you why BeautifulSoup show incorrect result - is Beautiful's issue ?

Comment: @LittleChicken yes, it's just the BeautifulSoup standard parser is less powerful than the regex parser from lxml. If you found the answer to be correct, then you can mark it as the correct answer.